# TikZ: Adding a coordinate to parallel location of two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add a coordinate where a line parallel to my `v\cos(\gamma)` would be located if it started from point `P7`.
I am not sure how to move those two lines to that location parallel to my original though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45,
  scale = 1.25]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (P1) at ($(O) + (-30:1.5cm and .75cm)$);

  \draw[-latex] (P1) arc (-30:310:1.5cm and .75cm) coordinate (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 1.75) node[above, scale = .75] {\(\mathbf{h}\)};
  \draw ($(P1)!.5!(P2)$) circle (.18cm) coordinate (P3);
  \draw[blue] (O) -- ($(P3)!.18cm!(O)$) node[scale = .75, pos = .5,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(\mathbf{r}\)} coordinate (P4);
  \draw[dotted, blue, name path = line] (P4) -- ($(P4)!.36cm!(P3)$)
  coordinate (P5);
  \path[name path = aux] (P5) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line and aux}, -latex, blue] (P5) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.5cm!(P5)$) node[scale = .75, shift = {(.25cm, -.2cm)}]
  {\(v\cos(\gamma)\)};
  \draw[dotted, name path = line2, blue] ($(P4)!.5!(P5)$) -- (P1)
  coordinate (P6);
  \path[name path = aux2] (P6) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line2 and aux2}, -latex, blue] (P6) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(P6)$) node[scale = .75, shift = {(.25cm, .2cm)}]
  {\(v\sin(\gamma)\)} coordinate (P7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, the whole picture is significantly easier to handle if you start from the satellite as a node at a particular angle and go towards the origin.

Comment: @percusse can you elaborate on that and provide a small example by what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the end point of the `cos(\gamma)` arrow is called `P8`, you can use the `calc` library to calculate the difference vector of the start and end points of that arrow (`P5` and `P8`), which you can then use as a relative coordinate (using the `+` operator):

```
\draw [red, -latex] (P7) -- +($(P8)-(P5)$);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap = round, line join = round, >=triangle 45,
  scale = 1.25]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (P1) at ($(O) + (-30:1.5cm and .75cm)$);

  \draw[-latex] (P1) arc (-30:310:1.5cm and .75cm) coordinate (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (O) -- (0, 1.75) node[above, scale = .75] {\(\mathbf{h}\)};
  \draw ($(P1)!.5!(P2)$) circle (.18cm) coordinate (P3);
  \draw[blue] (O) -- ($(P3)!.18cm!(O)$) node[scale = .75, pos = .5,
    fill = white, inner sep = 0cm] {\(\mathbf{r}\)} coordinate (P4);
  \draw[dotted, blue, name path = line] (P4) -- ($(P4)!.36cm!(P3)$)
  coordinate (P5);
  \path[name path = aux] (P5) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line and aux}, -latex, blue] (P5) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.5cm!(P5)$) coordinate (P8) node[scale = .75, shift = {(.25cm, -.2cm)}]
  {\(v\cos(\gamma)\)};
  \draw[dotted, name path = line2, blue] ($(P4)!.5!(P5)$) -- (P1)
  coordinate (P6);
  \path[name path = aux2] (P6) circle [radius = 1bp];
  \draw[name intersections = {of = line2 and aux2}, -latex, blue] (P6) --
  ($(intersection-1)!.75cm!(P6)$) node[scale = .75, shift = {(.25cm, .2cm)}]
  {\(v\sin(\gamma)\)} coordinate (P7);
  \draw [red, -latex] (P7) -- +($(P8)-(P5)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not that you may know, but why would Qrrbrbirlbel delete is answer?